# Total Quantity Discount in Paypal Checkout

Tags: paypal, discount

In Paypal I want to give a discount for total quantity ordered of multiple items.  For example 3 pcs of Item 1 and 2 pieces of Item 2 qualify for a 10% discount because a total of 5 pieces were ordered

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call their support? They will give you simple, fast and correct solution.